# how to navigate(redirect) to another page in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to redirect to another page(Page-II) when a button clicked but unfortunately that another page component loads on the same page(Page-I). Here what I tried so far :

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="register()"
  mat-raised-button class="searchButton" type="button">Register</button>
  <button (click)="profile()"
  mat-raised-button class="searchButton" type="button">Profile</button>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path : 'register',
  component : RegisterComponent
},
{
  path : 'profile',
  component : ProfileComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private router: Router ) {}

    register = function () {
      location.pathname = ('/register');
    };
    profile = function(){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
    };
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**Note:** I know that profile loads on same page but trying to redirect register.html when register button clicks on another page.

Answer (score 5):

Can you try this:

```
register() {
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
}
```

Comment: console doesn't show any error ,but button didn't response anything

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I'm new so didn't know anything about jsfiddle...what's that?